# rows disappear when I try to add a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

So, i'm trying to follow along with [this example](http://railscasts.com/episodes/165-edit-multiple). I'm trying to translate it to my own own project where I have a set of rows that are displayed based on the results of applying the search criteria in a first form. I'm trying now to put a second form around the results to provide the administrator with checkboxes to be able to edit several of the rows displayed at the same time. however, when i try to put a form around the results, the results disappear altogether.

Here's the relevant piece of my controller:

```
  def index
    @search = Distribution.workflow.search(params[:traits_searchable_search])

    respond_to do |f|
      f.html  {
        @report = @search.paginate(:page => params[:page])
        render :action => 'index'
      }
      f.csv do
        send_data @report.to_csv, :type => "text/csv", :filename => "distribution_workflow_report.csv"
      end
    end
  end
```

the view is nothing special. but i'm trying to wrap this tag (i've also tried removing the `:method => :put` piece and it's worth noting that the path provided to the form_tag is the page that's being displayed for now until i figure out how i'm going to get the routing to work):

```
<% form_tag admin_distributions_workflows_path, :method => :put do %>
```

around this table:

```
  <table class="standard-grid">
<tr>
  <th class="first"></th>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>Customer</th>
  <th>Customer Email</th>
  <th>Resume URL</th>
  <th>Partner</th>
  <th>Partner Email</th>
  <th>Status</th>
  <th>Assigned To</th>
  <th>Comments</th>
  <th></th>
</tr>
<% @report.each do |row| %>
  <tr>
  <td><%= check_box_tag "row_ids[]", row.id %></td>
  <td>
    <%= row.owner.id %>
  </td>
  ....
</td>
</tr>
<% end %>
  </table>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Rails 3 you have to use `<%=` format with `form_for` and `form_tag`

```
<%= form_tag
```